# Html Form in the Servlet will hit the browser

Tags: java, servlets

I have 2 servlets in my application and from 1st servlet i will call the second servlet like below:

```
public FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) {
     out.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"> \n");
        out.write("<html><head><body onload=\"document.forms[0].submit()\">\n");
        out.write("<form method=\"POST\" action="/Demoproject/secondServlet">\n");
        out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"resourcePath\" value=\"" + callbackUrl + "\"/>\n");
        out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"locale\" value=\"" + locale + "\"/>\n");
        out.write("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rspjRequest\" value=\"" + true + "\"/>\n");
        out.write("</form>\n</body>\n</html>\n");

}

}
```

So according to above html form the flow goes to second servlet which is configured in `web.xml`.

My question is:

> Is the html form in FirstServlet.java will go to the browser?

Comment: what do you mean by `go to the browser` clarify what do you want?

Comment: I mean to say that is the form is the html code, which will understand by browser, Will it go to the browser before going to SecondServlet as mentioned actionUrl while executing the application in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will go to the browser first

since `document.forms[0].submit()` is a javascript function and html you written  is a clientside languages and will only execute in the browser.

```
FirstServlet--->Browser---applies the javascripst submit by checking form code--->SecondServlet
```